# How to make search query to get all Objects in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I am creating a Realm object like below

```
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {

    @objc dynamic var ID = 0

    @objc dynamic var notificationTitleString = ""
    @objc dynamic var notificationBodyString = ""
    @objc dynamic var notificationDateString = ""
    @objc dynamic var notificationType = ""
    @objc dynamic var notificationUrl = ""
    @objc dynamic var notificationActivity = ""
    @objc dynamic var notificationIsRead = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ID"
    }
}
```

I am using the below method to get a particular item type

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class DBManager {
    private var database: Realm
    static let sharedInstance = DBManager()

    private init() {
        database = try! Realm()
        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
    }

    func fetchNotificationType(type: String) -> Results<Item> {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "notificationType = %@", type)
        let results : Results = database.objects(Item.self).filter(predicate)
        return results
    }
}
```

Using the above fetchNotificationType method i am able to get a single object, But i want all the objects in a single query. I do not know how to do that, I am trying Realm for the first time.

I searched SO, but i did not get any related answers.

Comment: As per the documentations, it should return all the results with the filter you have provided. can you confirm if there are multiple records present in your database for the type you are passing.

Comment: Yes, It is returning all the results. I only taking one object, after removing that i got it. Thank you @BhavinKansagara